# $compile tpload in clean URL AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have error like this `Error : [$compile] tpload` when i try to have clean url from here : https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Here is my code
JS:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
            function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {


                 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                $routeProvider.when('/', {redirectTo: '/datatables'});
                $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/page-404'});



                $routeProvider.when('/documentation/index', {
                    templateUrl: 'documentation/index.html'
                });



                $routeProvider.when('/datatables', {
                    templateUrl: 'datatables.html'
                });



                $routeProvider.otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/datatables'
                });


                }



        ]);
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cleanUI">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Template</title>

  <!-- Angular Version Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>


 <base href="/">
</head>
```

Have you any ideas?
Thanks for answers in advance!!!

Answer (score -1):

Your js code have some issues. You have to correct it as this

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
        function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when('/documentation/index', {
                templateUrl: 'documentation/index.html'
            }).when('/datatables', {
                templateUrl: 'datatables.html'
            }).when('/page-404', {
                templateUrl: 'page-404.html'
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise('/page-404');

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Sanjeew "Error: [$compile:tpload]"